# Why is there so much crema on my espresso?

Tags: espresso

I buy fresh beans of lighter roasts, grind a few minutes before extraction, pull a double shot normale, and end up with a lot of crema, I mean a lot!

Right when I'm done, the top 90% of the shot is crema moving around like the head on a fresh Guinness. After it dissipates for 30-60 seconds, I'm left with roughly a centimeter of crema of light color.

Crema is a pretty bitter flavor, so I wonder if there is something I'm doing to cause this type of extraction, and what can I do to improve on my technique?

Comment: As you seem to indicate that it's a problem, I'd have to say that yes, there's such a thing as too much.

Comment: @Joe Where did I indicate that this is a problem?

Comment: it looks to me like you were commenting on the bitterness ... if you bitter, then it's a good thing.  Many tastes are personal.  (I like spicy food ... but where I consider it bland, others might consider it overpowering).

Comment: For me personally, I believe that having a stronger bitterness note at the start of the shot overpowers the balance.  But it's just at that beginning.  I'm curious to see what some of the experts on here have to say :)

Comment: What type of coffee machine are you using? It seems that a lot of air is getting into the crema thus forming such a thick layer.

Comment: @Trogdor I've been using a Breville Infuser for about two years now. I've been tinkering with technique and am just now getting these results, so it's definitely not the machine. Thanks

Comment: I think this question is completely fine. People probably didn't like the "good or bad" bit and the question in the title, but the real question is what's causing it and how to avoid it, and that's a great thing to ask.

Comment: @Jefromi fair enough

Answer (score 2):

Crema is basically carbon dioxide fizzing up the coffee oils. By the description you're giving, it is likely to be too much. Your beans could be too oily and/or too fresh. It could be a combination of the type of beans / blend / or the way it's roasted.

Just as a guide, it is best for the beans to rest for around about a week after it's roasted. And if your beans end up soaking in oil, that is not good!